# Force a link to download an MP3 rather than play it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ive got an anchor link

```
<a href="http://bucket_name.amazonaws.com/uploads/users/4/songs/7/test.mp3">Download</a>
```

How do I make it so when a user clicks on it, it actually opens a popup asking the user to save the file instead of trying to play the file on the browser?

**EDIT:**

I was reading this [article](http://www.therailsway.com/2009/2/22/file-downloads-done-right).

```
  def download
    data = open(Song.first.attachment)
    send_data data.read, :type => data.content_type, :x_sendfile=>true
  end
```

The article suggest using x_sendfile, since send_file takes up an http process with the potential risk of hanging the app until the download is completed.

Second, I am using send_data instead of send_file, which seems to work if the file is remote (i.e. hosted on Amazon S3). As suggested by this [article](http://adamloving.com/internet-programming/send_file-and-remote-files-ruby-forum).

The article, I mentioned was posted on 2009. Is x_sendfile=>true still necessary? Will it hang the app if it isn't included?

Should I really be using send_data or send_file?

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. The only change I had to make was tu use data = open(Song.first.attachment_url), because otherwise I was getting an error: 'can't convert Paperclip::Attachment into String'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can manage your file downloading with separate controller, if you don't want to eal with HTTP server configurations.

So you can [send_file](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file) with `disposition` option as `attachment`.

Comment: Does this take up a signle http thread? i.e. Will the app hang until the file download is completed?

Comment: I get: Cannot read file http://actual_bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/users/4/songs/7/test.mp3. My method looks like: def download
    send_file Song.first.attachment, :type=>"application/mp3", :x_sendfile=>true, :disposition => 'inline'
  end

Answer (score 5):

Depends on how you / where you serve the file itself. I do not have experience with ruby but if you can alter the headers(most platforms offer this option) of the http response you can force a download. This requires:

```
Content-Type: application/force-download
```

I guess it will use "Content-type: application/octet-stream" by default which will cause the browser to play it.

But this will only work if you have control over the server/location that holds the actual file since you need to change the response when the file is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

### Skip The Controller Action

You don't even need the `download` controller action, you can just generate a download-friendly link like so:

#### In your `attachment.rb`

```
def download_url
  S3 = AWS::S3.new.buckets[ 'bucket_name' ] # This can be done elsewhere as well,
                                            # e.g config/environments/development.rb

  url_options = { 
    expires_in:                   60.minutes, 
    use_ssl:                      true, 
    response_content_disposition: "attachment; filename=\"#{file_name}\""
  }

  S3.objects[ self.path ].url_for( :read, url_options ).to_s
end
```

#### In your views

```
<%= link_to 'Download Avicii by Avicii', attachment.download_url %>
```

If you still wanted to keep your `download` action for some reason then just use this:

#### In your `attachments_controller.rb`

```
def download
  redirect_to @attachment.download_url
end
```

*Thanks to [guilleva](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16426114/293280) for his guidance.*

Comment: The 'model method' above doesn't work as-is. The `url_for` method in the aws-sdk is used on an S3Object whereas the `s3` variable declared above just fetches the bucket. You'll need to add `.objects[ 'key' ]` to the end of that line for it to work.

Comment: @DanWeaver You're absolutely right. I've updated it to reference the object instead of just the bucket now. Have a looksy.

Comment: I get a dynamic-constant-assignment error when I try this.

Comment: @ddonche Try moving `S3 = AWS::S3.new.buckets[ 'bucket_name' ]` to the top of your `attachment.rb` file so it's not redefined every time `#download` is called or using lowercase `s3`.